# Relacionamento na tabela com Include não funciona

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Não consigo fazer minha tabela pai incluir a dependente:

```
var medicos = TabelaMedico.Include(m => m.Especialidade).ToList();
```

Apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Não funciona por quê? Dá algum erro? Os dados não vêm? Por favor, seja mais específico.

Comment: Apresenta essa mensagem "CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `Include` que recebe uma expressão é um método de extensão e está no *namespace* `System.Data.Entity`, faltou incluí-lo.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, sabia que era coisa boba só não lembrava o que era , muito obrigado mesmo.
Só mais uma dúvida como se chama isso é Relacionamento mesmo?

Comment: @Mr.GMSOFT É relacionamento mesmo. `Especialidade` é uma  **propriedade de navegação** do relacionamento.